# FANN binding for Python 2.7 at Windows x64

Tags: python-2.7, fann

I'm trying to use FANN library with Python 2.7 at my windows 10 (x64).
After many tries I didn't find any clear way to do that. 
Can you tell me how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the simplest solution:

please install wheel:
`pip install wheel`

and then download and install this file:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fann2 fann2-1.0.7-cp27-none-win32.whl

`pip install Path_to_downloaded_file`

it's according to: 
https://github.com/FutureLinkCorporation/fann2/issues/11